# Intent not opening the original file

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, open-intents

I am trying to open a PDF file via `Intent` and it works fine but the only problem is that the original file is not opened instead a cached version is opened. I want to open the original file.
 
My Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(downloadmanager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId), "application/pdf");
Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```